# I'm experiencing problem of "Expecting element" in def nav_version = "2.7.5 for the creation of bottom navigation

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

My Android studio is complaining of "Expecting element" in "def nav_version = "2.7.5" after adding navigation dependency in build.gradle.kts.
Please, I want to know the element that's expecting me to add.

I have not tried anything because I'm still a beginner in android studio. Also, it doesn't give me any hints about the element that's actually expecting me to add, so, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.